# Class Attribute and metaclass in dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have some Python classes with class attributes and metaclass:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta

class OldProduct(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    c_type: str
    c_brand: str

    def __init__(self, name:str):
        self.name = name

class OldLegoBox(OldProduct):
    c_type = "Toy"
    c_brand = "Lego"

    def __init__(self, name:str, price:float):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

oldbox1 = OldLegoBox("Princess", 12.3)
print(oldbox1.c_brand)
oldbox2 = OldLegoBox("Knight", 42.3)
print(oldbox2.c_brand)
```

I would like to use `dataclasses` to improve the code: how to deal with the class properties `c_type` and `c_brand`?

I am thinking of the following which seems to fill my need:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Product(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    c_type: str
    c_brand: str
    name: str


@dataclass
class LegoBox(Product):
    name: str
    price: float
    c_type: str = field(default="Toy", init=False)
    c_brand: str = field(default="Lego", init=False)


box1 = LegoBox("Princess", 12.3)
print(box1)
box1.price = 1000
box1.name = "toto"
box1.c_brand = "some brand"
print(box1)
box2 = LegoBox("Knight", 42.3)
print(box2)
```

Is there a more appropriate approach?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Dataclass class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables) should be annotated with [`typing.ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar)

```
@dataclass
class Product(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    c_type: ClassVar[str]
    c_brand: ClassVar[str]
    name: str

@dataclass
class LegoBox(Product):
    c_type: ClassVar[str] = "Toy"
    c_brand: ClassVar[str] = "Lego"
    price: float
```

Using abstract classes doesn't actually get you anything here, as far as I can tell, because there are no abstract methods.  You can still create instances of `Product`, but they will not have `c_type` or `c_brand` attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this example doesn't not highlight the interest of metaclasses. I wanted to do a small extract from the code we use.

Comment: somewhat surprised to find something in the `typing` module having a runtime effect

Comment: It's more that the `dataclass` decorator inspects the type hints and uses them to generate code.  The `ClassVar` isn't actually doing anything, but rather the code consuming it knows what to do when it sees a `ClassVar`.